# Atom Remote-edit: Error occured when connecting to sftp

Tags: atom-editor

I am able via sftp using the same credentials on WinSCP, so why would I get an error message on Atom's remote edit package?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected this by modifying the sshd_config file on the server.

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I modified the following line:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes #changed from no to yes
```

then I restarted the ssh daemon:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

and that did the trick. I believe that Atom is sending passwords in clear text to the server, so using password authentication may cause issues unless you have PasswordAuthentication set to yes.